# android/webkit text-overflow: ellipsis not working

Tags: android, css, webkit

i am trying to get the following code to work on an androind 2.1 phone (HTC Sense UI):

```
h1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;   
}
```

however, the text-overflow property does not seem to work. has anybody else had this problem, or found a way to work around it?

Answer (score 5):

on Android 2.2 and 4, I use a line height greater than the font size (always em) with a display type "-webkit-box" and a vertical orientation.

Here is an example:

```
.myClass{
display     : -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-orient  : vertical;
text-overflow   : ellipsis;
-webkit-line-clamp  : 3;
overflow        : hidden; 
font-size       : 0.9em;
line-height     : 1.2em;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you have no width defined. If the element is allowed to get arbitrarily wide there is never going to be any overflow >**within**> the element. The element overflowing its parent wil not give you the desired effect.

Comment: That's not true in general if overflow is set to hidden and it has a containing element. I regularly do this and I get ellipsis. I have however noticed a problem on Android where you get a weird combination of clipped and ellipsis overlapping. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the 'ellipsis' is not working when your 'display' is set to '-webkit-box', reset to 'block' will do.
This may help: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=672944#c0