# Ellipsis on select element not working in IE9 and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a select list with a specified width. text-overflow: ellipsis is working only with Firefox v15. It is not working with IE7-IE9 and Chrome. Is text-overflow : ellipsis supported in IE7- IE 9 and chrome? If yes, what am i missing here? Is there a work around to get a similar effect? Please help. Thanks in advance. Html is given below

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select style="white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;width:70px;
">
  <option>Volvooooooooooooo</option>
  <option>Saabbbbbbbbbbbb</option>
  <option>Mercedesaaaaaaaaaa</option>
  <option>Audiiiiiiiiiiiiiii</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/17240/ellipsis-not-working-in-select-menu-options/p1

Comment: +1 interesting. Ellipsis in general is supported in all current browsers (IE from v6, Firefox from v7, Opera, Safari and Chrome all versions that I know of). But I've never tried ellipsis in a select.

Comment: @Miszy In IE9 ellipsis works fine with the div but not with the select list :(

Comment: Have you opened the link I posted? That's exactly what it says. It doesn't work for select options.

Answer (score 2):

I think that text-overflow:ellipsis is not supported in Chrome when you put it into a select element, you can see an exemple here: http://jsfiddle.net/t5eUe/

You can do this programming. For example, if you use Rails, you have the function "truncate", if you use php, you have the function "substr".

Answer (score 0):

I studied on net that `text-overflow:ellipsis` does not work on IE, when the container is a `div` or `width` attribute is not defined.

We can also use in IE [`-ms-text-overflow:ellipsis`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but is not recommended by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-overflow#Internet_Explorer_notes). 
and coming to chrome, I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036250/android-webkit-text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working) will solve your problem.

check this [browser compatibility for text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-overflow#Browser_compatibility).

If these all doesnt work then go through [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1022672) to achieve this which works on all browsers.

```
.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.ellipsis.multiline {
    white-space: normal;
}

<div class="ellipsis" style="width: 100px; border: 1px solid black;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</div>
<div class="ellipsis multiline" style="width: 100px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid black; margin-bottom: 100px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.ellipsis.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".ellipsis").ellipsis();
</script>
```

**jquery.ellipsis.js**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.ellipsis = function()
    {
            return this.each(function()
            {
                    var el = $(this);

                    if(el.css("overflow") == "hidden")
                    {
                            var text = el.html();
                            var multiline = el.hasClass('multiline');
                            var t = $(this.cloneNode(true))
                                    .hide()
                                    .css('position', 'absolute')
                                    .css('overflow', 'visible')
                                    .width(multiline ? el.width() : 'auto')
                                    .height(multiline ? 'auto' : el.height())
                                    ;

                            el.after(t);

                            function height() { return t.height() > el.height(); };
                            function width() { return t.width() > el.width(); };

                            var func = multiline ? height : width;

                            while (text.length > 0 && func())
                            {
                                    text = text.substr(0, text.length - 1);
                                    t.html(text + "...");
                            }

                            el.html(t.html());
                            t.remove();
                    }
            });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I think that this is not working on select element. Is there a way to achieve this on select element.[http://jsfiddle.net/F8Kdt/](http://jsfiddle.net/F8Kdt/)