# Word Wrap within select (dropdown) in IE8. Possible?

Tags: html, css, select, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu within HTML page where the option items are a long text. Problem is that IE8 cuts them off.

Is it possible that IE8 can support them?

This is the jfiddle that I am referring to and which works as I want but not in IE8.

http://jsfiddle.net/BtLBX/

### CSS

```
.myselect {
    width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.myselect option {

    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you read this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576906/ellipsis-on-select-element-not-working-in-ie9-and-chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/682764/select-dropdown-with-fixed-width-cutting-off-content-in-ie

Comment: Thanks guys. It was mentioned there.